# Timer in UpdatePanel causes some sort of full postback

Tags: c#, timer, updatepanel, postback

I have some sort of a strange problem, I have an update panel which is triggerd by a timer.

Also I have on this page is a function that calls the DB and retrieves data from it. the function does not being called from the update panel or even related to it.

the  problem is that I see in my log file that every time there is a tick and the update panel being updated there is also a call to my DB server (this function is in the page_Load section ) to retrieve the data again. but the page doesn't seem to do a full postback (It stays the same and doesn't looks like being reloaded)

my code:

```
<asp:Timer runat="server" id="UpdateTimer" interval="5000" ontick="UpdateTimer_Tick" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateTimer" eventname="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <span id="s1" runat="server"></span>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and code behind:

```
protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt = TimeConvertor.getCurrentGameTime();
    s1.InnerText = String.Format("Current game time: {0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", dt);
}
```

The function to retrieve data from the DB is in the page_load of the page.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Doron

Comment: After setting the InnerText, try calling `UpdatePanel1.Update()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Update panel doesn't refresh whole page, only controls inside update panel, but when Partial Update is executed all the server page life-cycle events occur, and view-state and form data are preserved, but when rendering page only part of update panel is rendered and returned to user.

Go to this link [Partial page rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386573.aspx)

and scroll to the section background.

Comment: This article helped me a lot to understand postbacks, I also recommend this article which cleared things out for me too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx